# Can I store the string result of that function and concat it to another string?

Tags: php, string, printf

I'm reading an array from db and i want to format that to provide a table like text for my telegram bot.

I try to use the sprintf php funtion to format the text, but when i try to put the result into a string the result is that any string was putted in the string.

This is my array:

```
// This is my complete array.
{
"result":true,
"error":"nothing",
"content":{
    "3269":{"Quantity":4,"Name":"Atom Seikhart"},
    "3273":{"Quantity":4,"Name":"Brunhild"},
    "3304":{"Quantity":3,"Name":"Isis"},
    "3319":{"Quantity":1,"Name":"Arthur"},
    "3329":{"Quantity":2,"Name":"Loki"},
    "3343":{"Quantity":1,"Name":"Chamimi"},
    "3351":{"Quantity":14,"Name":"Hanzo"},
    "3379":{"Quantity":8,"Name":"Lucifer"}
    },
"Total":37
}
```

And this is my php cycle and message send:

```
// This is my "select from db" function.
$res = get_event_rulers_breakdowns_by_id($mysqli, $value["Id"]);
$breakdown = $res["content"];
$message .= "\nThis is the event ruler breakdown (total " . $res["Total"] . "):\n";
foreach ($breakdown as $value) {
    $perc = round($value["Quantity"] / $res["Total"] * 100, 2);
    $stringa = "%+4s:%+4d\t(<code>%+4g%</code>)\n";

    // This work but don't format the text.
    $message .= $value["Name"] . ":\t" . $value["Quantity"] . " (<code>" . $perc . "%</code>)\n";

    // This dosen't work.
    $formatt = sprintf("%+4s:%+4d (<code>%+4g%</code>)", $value["Name"], $value["Quantity"], $perc);

    // This dosen't work too.
    $formatt = sprintf("%+4s:%+4d (<code>%+4g%</code>)", "aa", 123, 12.3);
    $message .= $formatt . "\n";
}
```

The actual result is:

And the expected result will be like:

```
Atom Seikhart: 4 (10.81%)
Brunhild:      4 (10.81%)
Isis:          3  (8.11%)
Arthur:        1   (2.7%)
Loki:          2  (5.41%)
Chamimi:       1   (2.7%)
Hanzo:        14 (37.84%)
Lucifer:       8 (21.62%)
```

or like:

```
Atom Seikhart:  4 (10.81%)
     Brunhild:  4 (10.81%)
         Isis:  3  (8.11%)
       Arthur:  1   (2.7%)
         Loki:  2  (5.41%)
      Chamimi:  1   (2.7%)
        Hanzo: 14 (37.84%)
      Lucifer:  8 (21.62%)
```

Comment: What is the actual result ?

Comment: str_pad and spaces instead of tabulation are your friends here: you should find the max length of the string for each column and than add extra spaces to each row (`$spaces_to_add = $max_row_length = $row_length`)

Comment: Is nothing :( @DanielE.

Comment: @user1597430 so for each column i have to calculate how many spaces i have to add? There's not a more efficent way to do this?

Comment: What is name of your array? `$breakdown`? And where `$res["Total"]` is set?

Comment: @Ingus $breakdown is the name of the array, and $res["Total"] is the sum of all quantities inside the array calculated before this script, but I know that it work well

Comment: in additional to my prev comment: str_pad counts the diff automatically, it requires only `$max_row_length` for the comment, OR you can calculate the diff manually and generate the string of spaces with a help of str_repeat function

Comment: @DanieleTentoni Why then you dont show us real array and also we need  `$res["Total"]` to be declared! It is hard to test without them . .. And takes time to do that ourselfs. ..

Comment: @Ingus I've edited my post, ty for your help!